# Migrating Alfresco 4.2 WCM sites to ACS 6.x

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, wcm

I am migrating Alfresco 4.2 Community to Alfresco 6.1 Community (201901 GA). I have successfully migrated to Alfresco 5.2 Community (201707 GA) based on suggested migration paths. When I upgrade to 6.1 and go to an existing site, I get the following error stating the 'documentLibrary' is not found. I also get an error viewing the sites "Recent Activity" dashlet.

I can create a new site and add artifacts successfully. It is the existing sites that fail with the following error.

```
14:10:34,094 ERROR [org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime] Exception from executeScript: 10170044 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10170227 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js': 10170226 Site container documentLibrary does not refer to a folder.
org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 10170044 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 10170227 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js': 10170226 Site container documentLibrary does not refer to a folder.
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.createStatusException(AbstractWebScript.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:171)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:512)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:587)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:656)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:428)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:308)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:399)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:210)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.AlfrescoWebScriptServlet.service(AlfrescoWebScriptServlet.java:43)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.ClearSecurityContextFilter.doFilter(ClearSecurityContextFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:798)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:808)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.alfresco.scripts.ScriptException: 10170227 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js': 10170226 Site container documentLibrary does not refer to a folder.
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:211)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:219)
    at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:181)
    at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1376)
    at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceException: 10170226 Site container documentLibrary does not refer to a folder.
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.findContainer(SiteServiceImpl.java:2844)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.SiteServiceImpl.getContainer(SiteServiceImpl.java:2751)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at net.sf.acegisecurity.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.CheckTransactionAdvice.invoke(CheckTransactionAdvice.java:54)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionAdvice$1.execute(RetryingTransactionAdvice.java:71)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:450)
    at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionAdvice.invoke(RetryingTransactionAdvice.java:74)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy120.getContainer(Unknown Source)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.script.Site$2.doWork(Site.java:503)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.script.Site$2.doWork(Site.java:1)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:623)
    at org.alfresco.repo.site.script.Site.getContainer(Site.java:499)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5._c_ParseArgs_getParsedArgs_15(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js:908)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5._c_getDoclist_20(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js:1060)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js:1352)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:405)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3508)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_slingshot_documentlibrary_doclist_get_js_5.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary/doclist.get.js)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:509)
    at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:207)
```

I've tried installing the 6.1.1 versions of the 'alfresco-wcmqs-*' amps found here: https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/alfresco/

My recent attempt was to use the artifacts from https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/org/alfresco/alfresco-wcmqs-distribution/6.1.1.1/ and applied the 'alfresco-wcmqs.amp' to 'alfresco.war', 'alfresco-wcmqs-share.amp' to 'share.war', and deployed 'wcmqs.war' to '[catalina_home]/webapps'.

```
13:45:28,121 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'patch.updateAdminUserWhenDefault' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/path/to/alfresco-content-services-community-distribution-6.1.2-ga/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-7.43.jar!/alfresco/patch/patch-services-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean] for bean with name 'org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart_processReceivedFeedbackTrigger' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart/job-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4699)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean] for bean with name 'org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart_processReceivedFeedbackTrigger' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/org_alfresco_module_wcmquickstart/job-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1392)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:663)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:630)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:507)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:462)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1096)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
    at org.alfresco.repo.admin.patch.impl.AdminUserPatch.afterPropertiesSet(AdminUserPatch.java:117)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1360)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1182)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

According to https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/alfresco-6-1-caching-content-store-error/m-p/88349, 'org.alfresco.util.CronTriggerBean' may need to be migrated but am unsure where.

It also appears that WCM was dropped from ACS: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-forum/web-project/m-p/64608

My question: Is applying the amp files the correct approach? What am I missing? Is migrating sites created by previous WCMQS modules not possible?

Comment: I am afraid, Alfresco didn't migrate the wcm module and the amp you found is an automated build without the required changes for alfresco 6.1. please check https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/wiki/ACS-6-Migration-Guide

Comment: I suspected as much and have seen the migration link you referring to. My question then becomes, "How do I access the document library created from sites in Alfresco 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Alfresco didn't migrate the wcmqs addon to be used in Alfresco 6.x. The module has been deprecated in 6.0 but I haven't seen an official notice for desupport.

Maybe you could setup / build a team in the community to take care about and to migrate that module. You could ask the [Order of the Bee](https://orderofthebee.net/) if there are others interested in cooperation for that migration.

Unfortunately I've no idea about the concepts and implementation of the WCM-QS addon but I guess the required metadata is stored in the custom model mentioned in the [Web Quick Start Developer Guide](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/web-quick-start-developer-guide/ba-p/290967). Even in your already migrated Alfresco the metadata should be already available but the module needs to be loaded during startup to also get the required functionallity which fails at least for the cron job registration you referenced in your error.

Some references which may help:

- [ACS 6 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/wiki/ACS-6-Migration-Guide)
- [Web Quick Start Developer Guide](https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/alfresco-content-services-hub/web-quick-start-developer-guide/ba-p/290967)
- [Installing and configuring Alfresco Web Quick Start](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/concepts/WQS-intro.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I also have not seen official unsupported documentation either. I will inquire with Order of the Bee.